# Memory violation when running Magick++ programs

Tags: c++, imagemagick

I'm having the issue running any of the Magick++ program, the programs linked and compiled successfuly but when i am running them i am getting the following error.

Inside Call stack Tab:

```
CORE_RL_Magick++_.dll!6b004bca() 
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for CORE_RL_Magick++_.dll] 
CORE_RL_Magick++_.dll!6affb2d8() 
>   button.exe!main(int __formal=-1990322582, char * * argv=0x53535330) Line 65 C++
```

Inside Output Tab:

```
'button.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x6b004bca in button.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00bbd458.
Unhandled exception at 0x6b004bca in button.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00bbd458.
First-chance exception at 0x6b004bca in button.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00bbd458.
Unhandled exception at 0x6b004bca in button.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00bbd458.
```

**Here is the things i've already tried.**

- Already tried re-installing the Visual Studio.
- Tried both x86 and x64 version of Magick++.
- When none of the above thing work i eventually re-installed the OS with complete format.

But I'm still getting the same error after re-installing OS , Visual studio and Magick++.

what is this Access Violation writing error ?

P.S: I am using Windos 7 x64 and I am already logged in as an Administrator.

Comment: You reinstalled the OS for a segfault!?!

Answer (score 1):

"Access violation writing" means that your program tried to write to a address it didn't have write access for. There are also access violations for reading and probably execution of code. You can easily get this:

```
char* ptr = "foo";
strcpy(ptr, "bar");
```

Suggestions:

- Create a debug-build of the program and look at the stack trace to find out what sequence of calls caused the error.
- Search the web for this error in this program and at the location you already found.

Comment: first of all stop working as admin is off topic and flamebait.  second, @Greatmailz, if you already tried searching the web, what is the solution?  you tell us... :p

Comment: i found the solution that say, run the memory diagnostic test so i did it..it took a while but still no luck

Comment: Thang, I don't understand why you consider the suggestion not to work as admin flamebait. When a beginner goes to desperate measures like reinstalling the OS, I believe it is in place to inform them that they shouldn't even need admin privileges, even if that is not the problem at hand that they're perceiving.

Comment: Great mailz, you need to continue your search. The mem diagnostic tool was one suggested way to find out what's wrong, this didn't work so look for other suggestions. Just so that you understand, people here usually don't help other people if they don't show some effort themselves. Finding a single solution online and trying only that does not count as effort. Read Eric S. Raymond's fantastic essay on "smart questions", which explains this in more detail. Finding a URL for that essay is left up to you!

Comment: Its not that i didn't look for the solution, 
I have been looking for the solution for the past 3 days, first the error was different and the program couldn't even compiling but eventually i figured out the way to fix this problem and it took me like 1 whole day, after compiling and linking successfully now i am getting this error as mentioned above i have searched a lot and all the available options that is mainly related to this problem in Magick++ have been tried, like setting dependencies, Linker setting etc..all have already been done..i even tried VC 2010 then i posted it as a question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to build Magick++ from source code and then use a project file for one of the Magick++ tests/demos as an example for how to create the project file for your own application.  Did you build from source code or are you using prepared DLLs from a binary install package?  Are you using Magick++ from ImageMagick or from GraphicsMagick?

Bob Friesenhahn (Magick++ original author)